# Get the locator from IWebElement

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm doing the following:

```
var locators = new ByChained(By.XPath("//div[@id='historyModal']//div[@class='modal-body']", By.ClassName("historyItem"));
var historyValues = WebDriver.FindElements(locators);

foreach (var historyValue in historyValues)
{
      if (!TrySelectHistory(historyValue))
      {
           // do something
      }
}

private bool TrySelectHistory(IWebElement historyValue)
{
    var historyValueChildren = historyValue.FindElements(By.XPath("./*"));

    if (historyValueChildren.Count < 2) return false;

    var selectButton = historyValueChildren[1].FindElement(By.TagName("button")); // would be great if I could get the locator of this element

    TestHelper.WaitForLoading(element: selectButton); // so I would pass that locator here instead of the element

    TestHelper.JavaScriptClick(element: selectButton); // so I would pass that locator here instead of the element

    return true;
}
```

As can be seen in the code, the `selectButton` I get from nested sequence of previous `By`. I would like to get the locator for this element, in order to prevent `StaleElementReferenceException`. Because in Selenium once a WebElement goes stale, it always stays stale, however, a locator could be used to keep trying to find the element until it gets a non-stale element.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass [By](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_By.htm) type to `WaitForLoading` and `JavaScriptClick`

Comment: that is not the problem. To problem is how would I retrieve the By locator of an existing `IWebElement` object.